# Ruby 1.9.3 syntax for block as argument

Tags: ruby-1.9.3

So in Ruby 1.9.2-p290 I can do this

```
content_for :something, do    
end
```

which is quite nice.
But that's a syntax error in Ruby 1.9.3-p125 and instead I need to do this

```
content_for(:something) do
end
```

Where can I find documentation about this syntax restriction?
Is there any other way it could be written in 1.9.3-p125?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just remove the comma:

```
content_for :something do    
end
```